# Which bit actually shift the << operator?

Tags: java, binary

I confused with an operator which provides arithmetic shifts `<<`, `>>` in Java

For example I have this binary number:

```
   0000 0101 // It is actually 5 in dec system
```

And now I want to shift this number to the left by 2 positions. I am doing this ( this is only concept of shifting bits) :

```
 0000 0101 << 2
```

And now I do not know: **if I need to shift high bit by 2 positions** and fill with zero in right side **OR I need to shift whole number (`101`) by 2 positions**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Second option :)
For instance, `0110001 << 2 = 1000100`

The other operators are:

- **signed right shift (`>>`)**.

  0011001 >> 2 = 0000110
  1011001 >> 2 = 1110110

  The leftmost bit is used as left padding. This is done to propagate the sign bit (highest bit).
- **unsigned right shift (`>>>`)**

  1110001 >> 2 = 0011100

  Since the number is considered unsigned, there is nothing to propagate, just pad with zeros!

Comment: Are you sure? because I am doing a program which counts how many bits are left in Int type (32bit) when I pass any finite integer to my variable;

Comment: If you left shift the high bit, it will disappear (since it was the highest, it cannot be higher). You may mean barrel-shift, when the highest bit becomes the lowest, but that's not a classic shift operation in computer science (more used in digital electronic).

Comment: So if I have a number 101 and I need to shift it by 2 positions, so my last '1' ( it is actually 10[1] ) goes 2 positions to the left and the result is: 1000?

Comment: You cannot get 1000 from 0101 in one operation. You can do ((0101 >>> 1) << 2) to get 1000, but that's 2 operations. Can you describe your issue by editing your initial question?

Comment: The high bits will only disappear once they are shifted past the highest bit supported by the underlying data type.  So, for a 32-bit `int`, `0b00000000000000000000000000110001 << 2` yields `0b00000000000000000000000011000100`.  For an 8-bit `byte`, `0b00110001 << 2 = 0b11000100`, but `0b00110001 << 4 = 0b00010000` (and some of the `1` bits finally get evicted).

Comment: At last I got it . Thank you!